# App iOS with BodyTracking - Interaction between user body and 3d models in AR

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I'm creating an iOS application that has an AR section.

In the AR I want the user's body to interact with a 3d model (or a generated text, even 2d, placed on the ground on a detected plane), when the user (detected by e.g. BodyTracking) is positioned on the text I want an audio file to start.

Is this feasible? What can I use to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the user holding the device? Or some other user in the scene?

Comment: Some other.. For example, smartphone on a tripod